# Styling checkbox with font awesome and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to style checkbox using font awesome with bootstrap. I am using two font awesome icons `fa-circle-thin` and `fa-check-circle`.

On mouse hover it should toggle class based on it is checked/unchecked and on click of check box javascript function should get called.

When trying to bind model as list if particular model property is False then 'fa-circle-thin' should be applied and if it is checked then 'fa-check-circle' should get applied.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: It will be more helpful if you created a jsfiddle or something similar to show what you tried.

Comment: I have tried from this http://output.jsbin.com/noqiwi/

Comment: your jsbin code neither have a checkbox and not any javascript function

Comment: Yeah.. but something I want to try like that only with checkbox !

Comment: something like this, https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help :

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked /><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-check"></i> One
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked /><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-check"></i> Two
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked /><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-check"></i> Three
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class*=icon-].icon-fixed-width {
  text-align: left;
}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$("[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  $checkbox = $(this)
  $icon = $checkbox.siblings("[class*=icon-]")

  checked = $checkbox.is(":checked")

  $icon.toggleClass('icon-check', checked)
    .toggleClass('icon-check-empty', !checked)
});
```

Note  : fontawesome should be included on page. (font-awesome.css / font-awesome.min.css)

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/mLuubpaq/

Comment: Can this be done on mouse hover ? if it is unchecked then on mouse hover show checked icon and vice versa

Comment: Yes, Check hover, mouseover handlers a little.

Answer (score 1):

See, if this can help you. I have tried in your jsbin code.
HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="divclass">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.divclass{
  font-size:5em;
  color:grey;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.divclass').click(function(){

  var ele = $(this).find('i');
  if($(ele).hasClass('fa-circle-o')){
     $(ele).removeClass('fa-circle-o');
    $(ele).addClass('fa-check-circle');
  }else{
    $(ele).addClass('fa-circle-o');
    $(ele).removeClass('fa-check-circle');

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a JS bin [here](http://jsbin.com/hoqexicuso/1). The checkbox is hidden so it will be as if the font-awesome icon is the checkbox. You can unhide the checkbox to see the effect.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divclass">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o">
      <input id='chk1' type='checkbox' style='display:none'/>
    </i>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.divclass{
  font-size:5em;
  color:grey;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.divclass:hover .fa-circle-o:before{
  content:"\f05d";
  color:green;
  opacity:0.4;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  $(".divclass").hover(function(){
    //Execute code on hover in
    $("#chk1").prop('checked', true);
  },function(){
    //Execute code on hover out
    $("#chk1").prop('checked', false);
  });

  //Below call back is used on click of the checkbox
  $(".divclass").click(function(){
    alert("checkbox clicked");
  });
})
```